# What is includepad parameter in StaticLayout's constructor?

Tags: android

I'm using staticlayout to draw text using this constructor;

```
 StaticLayout(CharSequence source, TextPaint paint, int width, Layout.Alignment align, float spacingmult, float spacingadd, boolean includepad)
```

I could not find in docs what is includepad parameter in StaticLayout constructor. Would be helpful if someone knows about it and points me out .
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would like to know this as well.  I assume it's a layout padding, but I can't find a way to set it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation from looking at the source code for TextView is that includepad indicates whether the static layout should include extra top and bottom padding in a given line to make room for text accents that go above the normal ascent and descent (for example whether the text lines include some extra padding for things like umlaut in German).

See TextView source code for setIncludePadding:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/oreo-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java